# jquery cloning elements with incrementing id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm busy with a form that needs to have an option to duplicate certain fields as many times as the user click, then also it needs to be E-Mailed off, therefore I'm currently on the passport field.

The only problem is, the way i set it up is that for each div element with the class off "passport" it creates an input field. So now where the fields ids are:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13

and when i use jQuery clone:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13

and what i need it to be:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23

but then how do i assign only the first set of ids to be associated with that one input, for it evaluates the value of the fields.

Anyways, Any help/advice greatly Appreciated.

Heres the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/A5naZ/

Heres the code:

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var pass = 1;
    val = 0;
jQuery('div.passport').each(function() {
    var index = "pass"+pass++;
    var passer = "<input class='pass' id="+'"'+index+'"'+" "+" maxlength='1' />";
    var passvalue = $(this).attr('value');
    jQuery(passer).appendTo('#pass');
});

$("#clone").click(function () {
    $('#pass').clone().insertAfter("#pass");
});

function Validatepass() {
    var passValue = '';
    $('.pass').each(function(){ passValue+=($(this).val());});    
    jQuery('#error p').remove();
    var error = jQuery('#error');
    var passNumber = passValue;
    var correct = true;
    if (passNumber.length != 13) {
        correct = false;
    }
    // if no error found, hide the error message
    if (correct) {
        jQuery('.pass').css("border","1px solid #9A8B7D");
    }
    // otherwise, show the error
    else {
        jQuery('.pass').css("border","1px solid #FF0000");
    }
    return false;
}

$('input.pass').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 8){
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).prev().val('');
        $(this).prev().focus();
         Validatepass();
    }
});  

$('input.pass').on('keyup', function(){
    if (this.value.match(/\d+/)) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.next('input').length) {
          $this.next().focus();
        } else {
          Validatepass();
        }  
    }
});
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="pass"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<div class="passport"></div>
<button id="clone">duplicate</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the click function to this

```
$("#clone").click(function () {
    var clonedObj=$('#pass').clone().insertAfter("#pass");
    clonedObj.find('.pass').each(function(){
       this.id='pass' + pass++;
    });
    clonedObj[0].id="WatEverUWant";
});
```

EDIT: check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codejack/A5naZ/1/)

EDIT 2: As per your second comment, if u mean changing the `id` of the cloned `div`, Added in the code.

Comment: perfect, any idea how i would submit this so that it associates the first set of fields with a "passport:12345678910111213" and then associate the duplicate fields with "duppassport:141516171819202122232526"?